# Transport endpoint is not connected error when trying view my flash drive

Tags: 16.04, mount, usb-drive, fuse

I plugged in my exFAT formatted flash drive into a Ubuntu MATE LiveUSB and when clicking the icon on the desktop I get this error:

> **The folder contents could not be displayed.**
>   Sorry could not display the contents of "FlashDrive": Error opening directory '/media/ubuntu-mate/FlashDrive': Transport endpoint is not connected

I closed the window and a few minutes later I got the "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has encountered an internal error" screen and the details said something about exfat and fuse. The same thing happens in Ubuntu GNOME. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an issue on the Live CD. Once you install Ubuntu, the issue goes away.